# Build python wheel with precompiled shared library

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel, python-extensions

When building a wheel of a Python extension module, how can I tell `setup()` to use an existing/precompiled shared library?

For awful horrible reasons, the SO/DLL has to be compiled by a build system that cannot be invoked by Python.  (FWIW it's compiled with the stable limited ABI.)  But I need my `setup.py` to bundle the library correctly.

Is there an option for this?  Is it possible to subclass `Extension` somehow and just return the existing library when asked to build it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a MANIFEST.in (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/) and include the files when creating a wheel this way.

So if you got all the shared libs somewhere in the source tree you can do

`global-include *.so`

Comment: This inspired me to use a `Command` subclass to do the copy.  I had to subclass `build` to trigger the copy command when appropriate, and subclass `Distribution` to force `bdist_wheel` to build an impure/binary (as in not `none`-type) wheel.  So thank you, have an upvote.